# Redirect using htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using a htacess file to remove the .php extension from my webpages.
However, I have a page called images.php and a directory called images (both in the root).

Therefore when the .php extension is removed from the images webpage, the site redirects to the image directory.

I've tried renaming the images file from image.php to imageone.php and then using a htacess redirect, but the problem persists

Can I overcome this in any way?

```
 # Remove .php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule .* $0.php

     #browser requests PHP
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
     RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

     # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
     RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
    </IfModule>



    Redirect 301 /images.php http://www.thewebsite.com/imagesone.php
```

Comment: The issue is you are rewriting the php file extension first, so the request /images.php ends up becoming /images which in turn gets translated to the /images/ directory

Comment: Thanks Derek, yes that what I think... Can i change the order?. I tried placing the redirect above the .php truncate rule but got the same issue

Comment: Try moving the redirect to above the mod_rewrite

Comment: Thanks Derek, that doesn't work , I even tried moving it to the top of the file

Answer (score 1):

You forget the `#` before your comment line `browser requests PHP`.

```
 # browser requests PHP
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo above

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mixing `Redirect` with `mod_rewrite` and have your rules in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^/?images\.php$ http://www.thewebsite.com/imagesone.php [L,NC,R=301]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# internally add .php to requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```